# Add number within Array and return the result listed in the Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am a new programming student working on a problem.  I've been given an array of numbers that i need to add a set value to each number and return the result (that shows the numbers and sum).  I'm not sure how to get the sum listed properly as part of the string.

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
```

Here is my code

```
a.map! {|x| "#{x} + 2 = (x + 2)"}
```

This is the result that is expected to be returned.

```
r = ["1 + 2 = 3", "2 + 2 = 4", "3 + 2 = 5"]
```

Result I'm receiving

```
["1 + 2 = (x + 2)", "2 + 2 = (x + 2)", "3 + 2 = (x + 2)"]
```

Comment: You are very close.  Try changing `(x+2)` to `#{x+2}`.  Use `map` rather than `map!` if you don't want to change `a` (usually you don't want to).

Comment: Thanks on the ! warning. I was testing some other options with it and didn't take it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to interpolate the result(x + 2):

```
def add_two(array)
  array.map { |x| "#{ x } + 2 = #{ x + 2 }"}
end

p add_two([1, 2, 3])
# => ["1 + 2 = 3", "2 + 2 = 4", "3 + 2 = 5"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple I was missing.